# sync framework not updating the existing row but uploading newly added rows

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using sync framework to sync data from onpremise(local) database to azure database .I have taken care of conflict also but after it is run fully is not uploading the new changes in existing row but inserting newly added row.can anyone suggest me why it is not updating existing row.Or is there any alternate soln for synchronise

Comment: what conflict type are you getting and how did you set the resolution?

Comment: i am getting LocalInsertRemoteInsert ,LocalDeleteRemoteDelete

Comment: those conflicts are normally not from an update... are you updating PKs? can you post the conflict for an update operation?

Comment: when i am updating my lcocal database record and then trying to synchronize with server then no data is synchronizing.I am synchronizing three local databases with one azure server database using three different scopes.

Comment: So an update is not firing the ApplyChangeFailedEvent? When you do an update, do you see the corresponding row in the tracking table updated?

Comment: @anitanegi7 did you found a solution? I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344046/syncframework-how-to-sync-all-columns-from-a-table/21345244?noredirect=1#comment32205414_21345244

Answer (score 1):

The situation is that Sync Framework, when found a conflict, don't know what to do.
A conflict is like your case, where the same row have different values between local and remote.

In this case you need to code your own ApplyChangeFailed method. 
In this doc it is covered: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761628.aspx