# SyncFramework: How to sync all columns from a table?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I create a program to sync tables between 2 databases.

I use this common code:

```
DbSyncScopeDescription myScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription("myscope");
DbSyncTableDescription tblDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Table", onPremiseConn);
myScope.Tables.Add(tblDesc);
```

My program creates the *tracking table* only with *Primary Key (id column)*.
The sync is ok to delete and insert rows.
But updating don't. I need update all the columns and they are not updated (For example: a telephone column).

I read that I need to add the columns I want to sync MANUALLY with this code:

```
Collection<string> includeColumns = new Collection<string>();
includeColumns.Add("telephone");
...
includeColumns.Add(Last column);
```

And changing the table descripcion in this way:

```
DbSyncTableDescription tblDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Table", includeColumns, onPremiseConn);
```

Is there a way to add all the columns of the table automatically?
Something like:

```
Collection<string> includeColumns = GetAllColums("Table");
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Table", onPremiseConn) will include all the columns of the table already.

the tracking tables only stores the PK and filter columns and some Sync Fx specific columns.

the tracking is at row level, not column level.

during sync, the tracking table and its base table are joined to get the row to be synched.

Comment: Thanks June.. Then why the sync is not updating all the rows data?

Comment: are you updating the PK? how are you updating? have you check for conflicts or errors via ApplyChangeFailed event?

Comment: June Hello,
I did a simple change and I got the a VERBOSE log:
http://www.frutafrescavirtual.com/log.txt

Comment: your log clearly indicates there was a conflict/error applying the change.

Comment: Thanks June... Then I don´t understand how to work Sync Framework. I did read that it uploads/downloads the changes from tables I selected.
How I tell to Sync F. that upload/download the changed rows too apart on new rows?
Example:  Local & Azure: 1 "Name1", 2 "Name2"...
If I changed locally 1 to "Other Name" and I do an upload I need "Sync F" changes in Azure: 1 to "Other Name". How I do it?
I read the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634928/sync-framework-not-updating-the-existing-row-but-uploading-newly-added-rows
But there is not an answer.
Thanks again

Comment: sync fx detects inserts/updates/deletes. you dont to tell and you cant tell it to cherry pick inserts, updates or deletes only. as i have mentioned, in your logs, it says there was a problem applying the change. check that.

Comment: Aaahhh @JuneT as you can see in the LOG it is not clear what happen.
Just a change in a text in a row why will occur a conflict.
Is there a way programmatically to get that "conflict rows" and tell to the sync framework that upload it and replace the row in the server azure?

Comment: it's covered in the docs...here's the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761628.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JuneT. Today I´ll with the info you sent me. ;)